# Finitely generated commutative rings with the same profinite completion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, profinite-groups, local-rings

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two finitely generated commutative rings. Assume that their profinite completions are isomorphic: $\widehat{R_1}\cong \widehat{R_2}$.

> Suppose that $R_1$ is a domain. Does it imply that $R_2$ is a domain as well?

The isomorphism between $\widehat{R_1}$ and $\widehat{R_2}$ is equivalent to the existence of a bijection $\phi: \operatorname{maxSpec}(R_1)\to \operatorname{maxSpec}(R_2)$ between the sets of maximal ideals, such that for all $M\in \operatorname{maxSpec}(R_1)$ the corresponding completions $(R_1)_{(M)}$ and $(R_2)_{(\phi(M))}$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Since this took me time to figure out: here are two non-isomorphic f.g. scalar rings with isomorphic profinite completions: $\mathbf{Z}[1/6]\times\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]\times\mathbf{Z}[1/3]$.

Comment: How about $R_2 = \mathbf{F}_p[x,y]/(xy)$ (two lines intersecting at a point) and $R_1 = \mathbf{F}_p[x,y]/(y^2 - x^2(x-1))$ (irreducible nodal cubic)?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: From the profinite completion you can read off the number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points. This is $2p-1$ for $R_2$ and $p-1$ for $R_1$, so the completions are not isomorphic. In general, I guess zeta functions could be an approach to the problem.